# Intellisense for CUDA in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I've properly installed VS 2008 and CUDA drivers and all. I'm able to compile .cu files and also i've added Syntax highlighting from usertype.dat file i'm also including required header files but still intellisense is not working properly. Can we have intellisense without Visual Assist in VS 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps i used for enabling cuda intellisense in VS 2008.

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to CUDA Toolkit directory.
3. Open the folder named extras.
4. Open the folder named visual_studio_integration.
5. Run the file "gpucomputing_intellisense.reg"
6. Press ok for the prompt.
7. Restart the system.

Thats all. :)